# Output to terminal (from bash script) in precise, 1-second increments

Tags: bash, time, sleep

I wrote a [kitchen timer for the terminal](https://github.com/rlue/timer) a while back (macOS only for now, unfortunately). It runs for a specified period of time, and then exits and sounds a bell:

[image: timer demo gif]

It does this by looping over some logic *n* times (where *n* is the number of seconds specified), adjusting the terminal output and `sleep`ing for 1s within each loop.

I've noticed that it actually takes a small amount of time longer to complete than specified:

```
$ time timer 0.05
[13:18] Time expired

real    0m3.289s
user    0m0.118s
sys     0m0.098s

$ time timer 0.1
[13:18] Time expired

real    0m6.362s
user    0m0.134s
sys     0m0.127s

$ time timer 0.2
[13:19] Time expired

real    0m12.496s
user    0m0.166s
sys     0m0.183s
```

It looks like all the logic around each `sleep 1` takes a small amount of time, and over a fifteen-minute period, those milliseconds add up. And when I set the timer to ring at repeating intervals (*e.g.,* once every fifteen minutes indefinitely), then I can start it at 11a, have it ring at 11:15 and 11:30 etc., but by the end of the day, it's ringing at 4:07 and 4:22 or some such.

Any ideas on how to run a timer that updates the output one second at a time, but faithfully measures long spans of time?

Is this a better job for C than a bash script?

Comment: A timed alarm will have better predictability but there is no way on a general-purpose consumer OS to guarantee any particular precision. If this is a critical application (kitchen timer? I guess that sounds like it is) you need to switch to a real-time OS. There used to be patches for this for the Linux kernel but I don't know what their current status is.

Comment: If you showed us your code, perhaps we could shave off a few things to make it more reliable. As it is, your question is borderline off-topic (there's a close reason which says "my code isn't working" questions on Stack Overflow need to include the code which isn't working). Though perhaps see also how to post a [mcve]

Comment: When talking about precision, it's important to quantify. Do you need millisecond, microsecond, or nanosecond precision? I'm guessing in this case decisecond accuracy would be more than sufficient.

Comment: Looking at the code, I see a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) on [line 59](https://github.com/rlue/timer/blob/master/bin/timer#L59)

Comment: With Python and threads, I think you could simplify the code substantially and have the timer update pretty much independently from the other code. Calculating what to splash onto the display the next time the timer needs to be updated ahead of time would help improve precision, too (beginning to calculate what to display when it's time means you have already lost).

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, @tripleee. My intention was to pose a generalized question and illustrate through the real-world problem I'm facing, not to ask for a solution to the real-world problem I'm facing. To clarify, I'm asking about precision in **regularity** (_e.g.,_ perform some operation once per second, not necessarily on the dot, but such that 1800 such operations runs very almost exactly 30 minutes, rather than accumulating a few milliseconds of lag from outside computation every second). I'll look into what can be done with threads.

Comment: Sounds more suitable for [su] then. But yeah, programmatically, having something timed to wake up on the second is going to avoid accruing the overhead you are asking about. (Just take care to make sure what it does takes less than a second, even under extreme conditions!)

Comment: The comments about nanoseconds are slightly tongue in cheek but there *are* industrial applications where really that sort of thing is required. I have no idea how exactly they achieve that, and I guess you don't really want to go there with your question. Putting PRECISE in big letters has the potential of grabbing the attention of that particular crowd so maybe don't do that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$( date +%s )
remain=$(( $1 * 60 ))    # supply minute(s) in integer as an argument
finish=$(( $now + $remain ))

while [ $remain -gt 0 ]; do
    remain=$(( $finish - $( date +%s ) ))
    mm=$(( $remain / 60 ))
    ss=$(( $remain - $mm * 60 ))
    printf "%02d:%02d" $mm $ss
    sleep 1
    echo -ne "\r"
done

# ring a bell or tell something here
```

It will be mostly accurate in a long term but the displayed clock occasionally skips by one second to absorb accumulated time difference.  I'm not sure if the phenomenon is acceptable.

Comment: This is great. I find that now timers sometimes terminate a little early or a little late, but never by a margin of >0.5s each. This might still accumulate some error over multiple intervals, but that's a separate design flaw for me to address. Thanks so much!